# How to solve a differential equation $y=xy'+\ln y',\ \ y(-1)=-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have to find a particular solution to the following differential equation:
>   $$
> y(x)=xy'+\ln y',\ \ y(-1)=-1
> $$

My attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&y'=t(x)\Rightarrow y=xt+\ln t\Rightarrow y'_x x'_t=tx'_t=x'_t t+x+\frac{1}{t}\Rightarrow x+\frac{1}{t}=0\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow t(x)=-\frac{1}{x}\Rightarrow y=\frac{x}{-x}+\ln\left(\frac{1}{-x}\right)\iff y(x)=-1-\ln(-x).
\end{aligned}
$$
In the end, my general solution matches the particular one. Is it fine or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Clairaut equation
$$
y=xy'+f(y')
$$
with a family of linear solutions $y'=C$,
$$
y=Cx+f(C)
$$
and the singular solution / envelope $x=-f'(y')$ which can be solved here as $y'=-\frac1{x}$, which is only valid for $x<0$ as only positive $y'$ are admissible as arguments for the real logarithm. Inserted this gives
$$
y=-1-\ln|x|, ~~ x<0.
$$
At points of tangency, one can switch from one solution to the other, so that there is also an infinite amount of composite solutions with linear and logarithmic segments.

---

Your error is that you can only solve $y'(x(t))=t$ whenever the derivative is not constant, you need a strictly monotonous segment for this parametrization. You have hidden this parametrization in the formula $y'(x)=t(x)$, but you use the inverse way in the chain rule application $\frac{dy}{dt}=y'_xx'_t=y'(x(t))x'(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a more accurate and complete answer now! This is Clairaut's equation, so let's go ahead

$y'=p$ , $y=xp+ln(p)$

$y'=p=p+p'(x+p^{-1})$

$p'(x+p^{-1})=0$

so $p'=0$ , $p=c$ , $y=cx+ln(c)$

$y(-1)=-1$

$-1=-c+ln(c)$ so $c=1$

$y=x$

$x+p^{-1}=0$ , $p=-x^{-1}$

$y=-xx^{-1}+ln(-x^{-1})=-1+ln(-x^{-1})$

then Both answers : $y=x$ or $y=-1+ln(-x^{-1})$

Comment: Hint: You can write function like the $\ln(x)$ in LaTeX with "\ln(x)" or "\operatorname{ln}(x)". This notation changes the formatting of the function form $ln(x)$ to $\ln(x)$ so that it is clear that it is a function and not a variable. This may be so clearly recognizable here, but it is important for more complex tasks.